# Стили ActionBar и NavigationDrawer

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно поменять стили (в основном интересует цвет текста) в ActionBar и боковом навигационном меню? Я использую тему Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. Пытался перегружать разные итемы и стили, но видимо не нашел нужный...

Я пробовал использовать вот такой способ:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MainTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">#212121</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MainTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#212121</item>
    </style>
```

Но не работает. Возможно не верно указаны родители стилей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MainTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MainTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Вот мой AppCompat, поменяете на свой =)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="BuffTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/dark_action_bar</item>
        <item name="background">@color/dark_action_bar</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/SubTitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SubTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Да, я видел этот вариант, но не могли бы Вы подсказать, какие родительские стили должны быть если я хочу использовать тему Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar?

Comment: проапдейтил ответ)